# Fund deposit on Polygon safe wallet whereas wallet is on gnosis chain

Tags: gnosis-safe, polygon, gnosis

I've created a safe wallet on the gnosis chain using the safe relayer:
https://gnosisscan.io/tx/0x1f41365850321f6ec1ee6d05acf44fc53fa56165fc5ef2f6139a67b06494b108#eventlog

ChainId being 100 and factory address: 0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/proxy_factory.json

Because of a miss usage of monerium, I've deposit funds on polygon blockchain (where there is no binding with safe, I only have a gnosis safe with this address)
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0fc2a8fd68AA5f76d0D878349ae92604A59E5EAE

Meaning that I now have a safe wallet in the gnosis blockchain and no access to the funds on the polygon one.

Is there a way to reuse the payload for contract creation in the gnosis chain so that at the end I have a gnosis chain safe and a polygon safe with the following address:
0x0fc2a8fd68AA5f76d0D878349ae92604A59E5EAE

And therefore retrieve the funds...
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately safe deployments addresses are deterministic so you should be able to deploy a new safe on Polygon using the exact same parameters that you used to deploy the one on Gnosis chain.

Could you please try this and let me know if it worked?

Thanks,
Louis

Comment: Hello Louis, I'm unfortunately unable to redo the steps, could you help me doing so ?

Comment: I've reached out to intercom support multiple times, unfortunately, the fact I've created it with the relayer made it slightly more complex than just replaying the request using metamask.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for hanging tight! You can deploy a safe on polygon mainnet by sending a transaction to this address `0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2`  using this transaction data:

```
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
```

We used [tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/gnosis-chain/0x1f41365850321f6ec1ee6d05acf44fc53fa56165fc5ef2f6139a67b06494b108) to extract transaction data from the call stack.

Hope it solves the problem. Best, Louis